Can't display arabic word when export razor page to PDF
i am using razor pages for making invoce and export it to pdf file
i am trying to export invoice details (invoice number ,company name ,....) to pdf but in the pdf the arabic word comes like this :ةروتافلا مقر.
i used all the windows font but to no avail this is my csthml.cs code
What should I do to be able to display Arabic words correctly, as well as display pages from right to left, noting that I am a beginner in this field?
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using AfterFix.Pages.Items;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace AfterFix.Pages.Sales
{
 public class NewSalesModel : PageModel
 {
     private readonly string _connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-9CABSPL\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mystore;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

     public SalesInfo salesInfo = new SalesInfo();
     public ItemsInfo itemsInfo = new ItemsInfo();
     public string errorMessage = "";
     public string SuccessMessage = "";

     // Fetch customers
     public List<SelectListItem> CustomerList { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();
     public List<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();

     public void OnGet()
     {
         using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
         {
             connection.Open();
             var query = "SELECT Id, Name FROM customers";
             using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
             {
                 var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                 while (reader.Read())
                 {
                     var customerId = reader["Id"].ToString();
                     var customerName = reader["Name"].ToString();
                     CustomerList.Add(new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Value = customerId,
                         Text = customerName
                     });
                 }
             }
             // Fetch items
             var itemQuery = "SELECT Id, ItemName FROM items"; // Adjust the query according to your database schema
             using (var itemCommand = new SqlCommand(itemQuery, connection))
             {
                 var itemReader = itemCommand.ExecuteReader();
                 while (itemReader.Read())
                 {
                     var itemId = itemReader["Id"].ToString();
                     var itemName = itemReader["ItemName"].ToString();
                     Items.Add(new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Value = itemId,
                         Text = itemName
                     });
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     public IActionResult OnPostGeneratePDF()
     {
         // Get invoice information from form
         string invoiceNumber = Request.Form["InvNo"];
         string invoiceDate = Request.Form["InvDate"];

         // Create PDF document
         using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
         {
             Document document = new Document();
             PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
             document.Open();

             // Font settings for Arabic text
             BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\times.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
             Font arabicFont = new Font(baseFont, 12, Font.NORMAL);

             // Add Arabic text to PDF
             Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("رقم الفاتورة: " + invoiceNumber, arabicFont);
             document.Add(paragraph);
             paragraph = new Paragraph("تاريخ الفاتورة: " + invoiceDate, arabicFont);
             document.Add(paragraph);

             // Add company name, item names, item prices, total price, etc. as needed

             document.Close();

             // Export PDF
             return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "invoice.pdf");
         }
     }
 }
}


take a look at this sample: https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/language-specific-examples, font used can be found in sample repo: https://github.com/itext/itext-publications-examples-java/blob/develop/src/main/resources/font/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf

this not work with me

@Guust, looks like it's iText 5, not iText 8 + pdfCalligraph

from where i can get iText8
